# Model properties returning empty

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Model which retrieves data from one table in a database, and two other Models (`Streets` and `Cities`) that retrieve data from two other tables. All of this information needs to be accessed from the `LandVehicle` Model. I'm having some trouble figuring out exactly how the to retrieve data from the other tables into the properties in the `LandVehicle` Model. Below is the class structure I'm working with:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=6)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=6)
    radius = Decimal(.06)

    @abstractproperty
    def streets(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def cities(self):
        pass

    @cached_property
    def nearby_vehicles(self):
        return Vehicle.objects.filter(lat__range=[self.lat - 2, self.lat + 2], lon__range=[self.lon - 2, self.lon + 2])

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class LandVehicle(Vehicle):

    @property
    def streets(self):
        name_substr = self.name
        if " " in name_substr:
            name_substr = name_substr[:name_substr.index(" ")]

        return LandVehicle.objects.filter(Q(streets__name__contains=self.name) |
                                          Q(streets__name__contains=name_substr) |
                                          (Q(streets__lat__range=[self.lat - self.radius, self.lat + self.radius]) &
                                           Q(streets__lon__range=[self.lon - self.radius, self.lon + self.radius])))

    @property
    def cities(self):
        name_substr = self.name
        if " " in name_substr:
            name_substr = name_substr[:name_substr.index(" ")]

        return LandVehicle.objects.filter(Q(cities__name__contains=self.name) |
                                          Q(cities__name__contains=airport_name_substr) |
                                          (Q(cities__lat__range=[self.lat - self.radius, self.lat + self.radius]) &
                                           Q(cities__lon__range=[self.lon - self.radius, self.lon + self.radius])))

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'landvehicles'

class Streets(models.Model):
    # Meta
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'streets'

class Cities(models.Model):
    # Meta
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cities'
```

I don't necessarily get an error from the way it's set up now, but accessing the data in the view, such as `vehicle.streets`, if `vehicle` is an instance of `LandVehicle`, is just an empty variable.

I understand that I will need to parse the data once I can retrieve it, but right now it doesn't seem to be retrieving anything (can't print anything out for it either).

**Edit/Update:**

By adding the `self` parameter to each of the properties (changed above), I receive an error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'streets' into field. Choices are: id, lat, lon, name
```

At least I get some sort of error now, but I'm still not sure how to access the properties.

Comment: By empty variable you mean `None`? Try to put some `print`s in there to see if the code is executed at all. Also the code looks weird - your methods are missing `self` (as a first parameter) everywhere.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko If I try to print text to the console within the properties (such as printing "Test" in the `streets()` property), it works, so it seems to be executed, but if I assign the query inside the property to a variable and print that, nothing prints to the console. I've added the missing `self` parameters to each of the properties and updated the post with some more information on the error.

Answer (score 1):

Ah of course, now I see it. The error says it - you're trying to use `streets` as a column in your `filter()` expression, but it is not a db column defined anywhere. You need to define the column as an ancestor of `Field` class (+ make a migration for it), and then you can use it in your db query.

You have to also rename the property `streets` so something else, if the db column will be called that way.

edit for the comment below: you can have both the things, but they cant obviously have the same name. So for example this way:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):

    # ...
    # a singular name
    street = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    @property
    def streets(self): # plural
        # you can use this instead of the 3 lines with `if` you have now
        name_substr = self.name.split()[0]

        #since the column is singular `street`, is needs to be singular in the query below too.
        return LandVehicle.objects.filter(Q(street__name__contains=self.name) |
                                          Q(street__name__contains=name_substr) |
                                          (Q(street__lat__range=[self.lat - self.radius, self.lat + self.radius]) &
                                           Q(street__lon__range=[self.lon - self.radius, self.lon + self.radius])))
```

As for your question what does `LandVehicle.objects.filter()` do is that it is a handy way to to write an sql query without actually writing the raw SQL query. Django then translates it into the query for you. So when you want to filter the db records by a street name, you have to have the `street` column in database, so the database can do the comparison above the data.

For example this bit: `Q(street__name__contains='foobar')` is translated to an sql query like `select * from vehicle where street LIKE '%foobar%'`. So obviously it is expected the column `street` needs to be there. Not only for filtering the data, but you also need to store these data.

If you dont understand how Django ORM works, go read this part of documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/

Comment: It's starting to make sense, but I must be completely confused as to what `LandVehicle.objects.filter(Q(cities__name__contains=self.name)` is doing. As you pointed out streets is not a column, but the end goal is for `streets` to hold a list of table rows (with all of their column data) to be able to parse it into a tuple. So to clarify, I should create a custom Field which will act as sort of a container for all of the row data?